# Class not present in JRE Emulation Library / cannot be used in client mode

Tags: java, intellij-idea, libgdx

I'm following the "simple game" tutorial in the libgdx wiki. At one point it asks me to do the following:

```
Rectangle bucket;
bucket = new Rectangle();
```

IntelliJ gives the following error message:

> Class 'java.awt.Rectangle' is not present in JRE Emulation Library so it cannot be used in client mode

Can someone explain what this means and how I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think something is wrong in your plugin of IntelliJ....and as far as I know there can't be anything wrong in JRE installation in your system...if you java is out of date then update it. Again set Plugin in your IntelliJ ..& I am sure you have not forgotten to add..

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
```

its good if you install JDK 8...

Comment: I'm using JDK 8 and Rectangle is indeed imported. :) Not quite following what you meant about setting the plugin?

Comment: I am using netbeans and its quite effective...I don't know about the interface of IntelliJ....if you want then you can switch to netbeans 8.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had imported...

```
import java.awt.*;
```

...which contains "rectangle".

Solution: remove that line and import:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
```